# Save the user from one model to the another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

What I want to do is, whenever I create a new message, I want the `sender` of the `Message` to be added to the `user` of that particular `Thread` (the `Message` its relating to).

How do I do that?  Can it be done by overriding the `save` method? I can do it in the views.py, but I was hoping it would be better if I can add it in the models.py itself. Any help will be very grateful. Thank you!

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    is_hidden = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='hidden_thread', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_hidden = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='hidden_message', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (unicode(self.thread.id), self.body)
```

Comment: can you post your view? where is `user` object coming from? Is `@login_required` on your view?? How are you creating the Message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to actively pull the user set as dm03514 showed, such as if you want to add users to the thread by default but maintain the ability to remove them from the thread many-to-many later, you can indeed do this by overriding the `save` method or by using a `post_save` signal.

`save` is good enough for almost all cases - the advantage of `post_save` is that it can more reliably distinguish between saving a new message and saving edits to an existing message. But if you're not creating messages with preselected PKs or loading them from fixtures `save` can work fine:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        probably_new = (self.pk is None)
        super(Message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if probably_new:
            self.thread.user.add(self.sender)
```

A signal would look like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def update_thread_users(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created']
    raw = kwargs['raw']
    if created and not raw:
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        instance.thread.user.add(instance.sender)

post_save.connect(update_thread_users, sender=Message)
```

And then review the docs on preventing duplicate signals in case of multiple imports:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Comment: Just what I wanted, the `save` method! Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry could you please elaborate what this means, `creating messages with preselected PKs or loading them from fixtures`. I want to know what drawbacks the save method will have.

Comment: It is possible in Django, although rare, to set the primary key of a new object prior to saving it. The above `save` method would then not detect that it's creating a new object rather than editing an existing one. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#explicitly-specifying-auto-primary-key-values The code that triggers signals makes an extra database call to determine this, so `created` is more reliable. Fixtures means using the `loaddata` manage.py command to import data from a file. Sometimes you don't want to run `save` side effects in the middle of that.

Answer (score 4):

You could lookup the reverse foreign key and get all the users for a particular thread without having to manually put it in `Thread`

Then you can get users associated with a thread by the reverse lookup:

```
User.objects.filter(message__thread=thread)
```

Comment: I think that's what the `sender` fk on `Message` already is. Also, you can do that query without separately pulling the user ids: `User.objects.filter(message__thread=thread)`. Although as always with joins vs. extra queries it's worth profiling the performance.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yes, totally missed that , tired, eyes, ty. Updated.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought of that. Thanks though!