# How do I run a method when a model gets created?

Tags: python, django

Currently I am using signals to fireoff the creation of my IPs when a new Subnet is created.

But some people in #django said the better way was to create a custom save() or let form handle it if there is ForeingKey.

Is there a more appropriate solution than using signals? If so can someone show me a code example?

My Subnet model (models.py):

```
class Subnet(models.Model):
    network_address = models.IPAddressField()
    subnet_prefix = models.ForeignKey(SubnetPrefix)
```

My IP Address model (models.py):

```
class IPAddress(models.Model):
    subnet = models.ForeignKey(Subnet)
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

My signal (models.py):

```
def subnet_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        # If this is a new object create ip_addresses in IPAddress table
        if created:
            create_ip_addresses(instance)
```

Comment: I would just use the signals if you already have them working.  Their only real down side is that they're marginally more complicated than a custom save. But the `created` argument covers some obscure cases that checking for a pk doesn't, and the `raw` argument is also useful.

Comment: I see that you've accepted the answer describing how to override `save`. There's nothing wrong with that approach for most cases, but my answer here might be useful for understanding the relatively obscure cases in which it's not the best choice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339562/save-the-user-from-one-model-to-the-another-model/20340365#20340365

Comment: That's a good response makes me feel better about using post_save signal in my app. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `save` method:

```
class Subnet(models.Model):
    network_address = models.IPAddressField()
    subnet_prefix = models.ForeignKey(SubnetPrefix)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super(Subnet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            create_ip_addresses(self)
```

Comment: Using the override save, am I able to tell if the object is new, or being updated? Because I want to create the IPs on object creation.

Comment: You have to check if self.pk is set before calling ``super(..).save(..)``. You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert).